# Lua script doesn't create file using tshark

Tags: lua, wireshark

I have a lua script which I found on github.(https://github.com/volvet/h264extractor) When I use it from wireshark, it creates a dump file from pcap.
But if I use from Ubuntu terminal like this: `tshark -X lua_script:rtp_h264_extractor.lua -r a.pcap`
It doesn't create any dump file. Is there any solution to this problem or this is how it should be?
Here is the code from lua script.

```
    local function extract_h264_from_rtp()
    local h264_tap = Listener.new("ip", "h264")
    local text_window = TextWindow.new("h264 extractor")
    local fp = io.open("dump.264", "w+")
    local seq_payload_table = { }
    local pass = 0
    local packet_count = 0
    local max_packet_count = 0
    local fu_info = nil
    
    local function log(info)
        text_window:append(info)
        text_window:append("\n")
    end
    
    if fp == nil then 
        log("open dump file fail")
    end
    
    local function seq_compare(left, right)  
        if math.abs(right.key - left.key) < 1000 then  
            return left.key < right.key  
        else 
            return left.key > right.key  
        end  
    end  
    
    local function dump_single_nal(h264_payload)
        fp:write("\00\00\00\01")
        fp:write(h264_payload:tvb()():raw())
        fp:flush()
    end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps it's a permissions problem.  Which directory are you running `tshark` from and do you have write permission into that directory?

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard Hello. Even if I have root permissions, it doesn't create any dump file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted lines which belong to Wireshark GUI and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't supply the complete Lua script so I downloaded it.  It's obvious this script was only written for the Wireshark GUI as it registers a menu item under Tools.  In other words:

```
register_menu("Extract h264 stream from RTP", extract_h264_from_rtp, MENU_TOOLS_UNSORTED)
```

The script simply won't work with `tshark`.  In fact, the script really should be prefaced with something like the following so it's that much clearer that it's not applicable from `tshark`:

```
if not gui_enabled() then
    return
end
```